# How delete a specific item in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs

[image]

How can i delete a coupon in this?
I searched and couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the 'state' key is stored as string value in localStorage, you need to get the value as JSON and parse it to get the required property to be deleted and set the localStorage again.

```
let stateObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("state"));
delete stateObj.coupon;
localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(stateObj ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("state"));
delete state.coupon;
localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(state));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.